# Should the "legal" tags be cleaned up on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, clean-up

For ones this is about the meta-tags:

- [license](/questions/tagged/license) x16
- [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) x66
- [ownership](/questions/tagged/ownership) x20
- [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright) x81
- [legal](/questions/tagged/legal) x90
- [attribution](/questions/tagged/attribution) x66
- [content-reuse](/questions/tagged/content-reuse) x15
- [copyright-infringement](/questions/tagged/copyright-infringement) x17
- [trademark](/questions/tagged/trademark) x18
- [plagiarism](/questions/tagged/plagiarism) x36
- [intellectual-property](/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) x9

Most of these tags cover the same type of questions (and are partly even tagged onto the same questions) and quite a few could be merged in my opinion.

- [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) => [license](/questions/tagged/license)
- [ownership](/questions/tagged/ownership) + [intellectual-property](/questions/tagged/intellectual-property) => [copyright](/questions/tagged/copyright)

Should we clean this up?